# « Il n’y a pas grand » peut-il introduire un nom au pluriel?

Tags: expressions, formulation, nombres

Exemple:

Bien franchement, il n’y a pas grand postes qui m’intéressent actuellement dans les offres d’emploi.

Au sens de:

Bien franchement, il n’y a pas beaucoup de postes qui m’intéressent actuellement dans les offres d’emploi.

On dit en revanche correctement: Il n’y a pas grand monde à la messe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Il n'y a pas grand* ne peut introduire qu'un masculin singulier sauf si on accorde *grand*.

Il existe de nombreuses formes de ce type qui peuvent suivre une ou plusieurs des formes verbales *n'avoir*, *n'y avoir* et *ne faire* entre autres :

- pas grand monde
- pas grand-chose
- pas grand mal
- pas grand cas
- pas grand mérite
- pas grand risque
- pas grand intérêt
- pas grand inconvénient
- pas grand danger
- pas grand avantage
- pas grande différence
- pas grande importance

Ce sont toutes des locutions assez figées. Il est plus ou moins risqué de tenter d'innover dans ce domaine :

> Il n'y a pas grand supporter dans ce stade. (?)

Ta suggestion risque de surprendre :

> ? Il n’y a pas grands postes qui m’intéressent.

d'autant plus qu'on ne peut pas, à l'oral, la distinguer de :

> Il n’y a pas grand poste qui m’intéresse. (?)

*Pas grande différence/importance* confirment que *grand* n'est pas invariable (sauf bien sûr dans *grand-chose*). On trouve donc aussi des occurrences au pluriel :

- Il n'y a pas grands changements.
- Il n'y a pas grands dangers.
- Il n'y a pas grands détails.
- Il n'y a pas grands commentaires à faire.

Comment: Remarque du temps jadis : « Il n'y a pas grand-mère poussée dans les orties aujourd'hui ! oukelédonk ? »

Comment: @Personne Dans les innovations je dirais.